# Smart diff for binaries

Tags: compare, diff, binaries

If you will compile the same sources on the hardware twice you will get different binaries. Do you know how to verify using any tools or scripts that content wasn't changed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) has binary comparison feature.